# Как сделать так чтобы бот в дискорде рандомил людей в канале? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Например, Я пишу команду в канал !random
И в этом канале 8 человек он рандомит двух людей: красный -@N/A, синий - @N/A. И в этом же сообщении он пишет всех участников канала например:
Синий - @N/A
Красный - @N/A
Все участники:
Player @Player
Player1 @Player1
Player2 @Player2. И так далее, и главное чтобы бот именно смотрел канал в котором сидит тот кто написал команду. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from random import shuffle

@bot.command()
async def random(ctx):
    all_players = ctx.author.voice.channel.members
    shuffle(all_players)
    team_1 = all_players[:len(all_players) // 2]
    team_2 = all_players[len(all_players) // 2:]
    await ctx.send("Team1:\n" + "\n".join(str(i) for i in team_1))
    await ctx.send("Team2:\n" + "\n".join(str(i) for i in team_2))
```

Comment: Код не работает

Comment: Пришлите ошибку сюда, в комментарии

Comment: Нет, код работает, но я хотел чтобы бот рандомил людей именно в голосовом канале. Например человек пишет команду в чат и он в это время сидит в голосовом канале из 8 человек. И бот рандомит двух людей из этого голосового канала и пишет в чат ники тех кого зарандомил.

Comment: А зачем тогда пишите, что код не работает, и в описании проблему вы не указали тип канала, так что по факту я выдал верное решение, да и в чём проблему изменить с текстового чата на голосовой?

Comment: Извините, моя ошибка. А так спасибо, помогли.

Comment: Поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку у ответа

Comment: Я домой приду и проверю код

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'voice'

Comment: Исправил.........

Comment: Не работает, он как будто не видит Войс канал

Comment: Её надо на воисе юзать, и можете сделать проверку на нахождение на воисе

Comment: Ну а я что делаю

Comment: В чём ошибка?...

Comment: Бот не рандомит он просто пишет: team_1:, team_2:

Comment: Я исправил код...